# Click random en una imagen desde sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli

quisiera hacer random click en la captura señalada ejemplo: le capturo un cuadro y que haga click en cada `(x, y)` al azar dentro de ese cuadro.

intenté hacerlo por mi cuenta guarde en una variable un numero random, cree unos if y si salia por ejemplo el numero 1 ejecutaba el click en la posición señalada, como tenia que hacer click en configuración de patrones y luego desplazamiento del objetivo, me toma mucho tiempo, logré hacerlo, hace más de 30 click random, pero si quisiera hacerlo para otro objetivo me tomaría demasiado tiempo volver a hacer lo anterior, esto lo hago para hacer un bot que haga click random, ya que se detecta el click en la misma posición, tengo esto pero no funciona como esperaba.

```
 from random import randint, uniform,random
    r = 
    w = 50
    h = 50
    for i in range(5):
        x = int(r.w * randint(1, 3))
        y = int(r.h * randint(1, 3))
        r.click(Location(x, y))
```

Todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde sikuli, espero que me puedan ayudar.